# Mysql query with group by and order by involving several tables

Tags: mysql

I'm having a problem regarding a query because i don't have all the records and i don't know why
This is the query

```
SELECT `ebspma_paad_ebspma`.`semana_dias`.`dia`,`ebspma_paad_ebspma`.`req_material_sala`.`sala`, `ebspma_paad_ebspma`.`req_material_tempo`.`inicio`, `ebspma_paad_ebspma`.`sala_ocupacao`.`id_ocup`, `ebspma_paad_ebspma`.`turmas`.`turma`
FROM `ebspma_paad_ebspma`.`sala_ocupacao` 
INNER JOIN `ebspma_paad_ebspma`.`semana_dias` 
ON (`sala_ocupacao`.`id_dia` = `semana_dias`.`id_dia`)
INNER JOIN `ebspma_paad_ebspma`.`req_material_sala` 
ON (`sala_ocupacao`.`id_sala` = `req_material_sala`.`idsala`)
LEFT  JOIN `ebspma_paad_ebspma`.`req_material_tempo` 
ON (`sala_ocupacao`.`id_tempo` = `req_material_tempo`.`idtempo`)
LEFT  JOIN `ebspma_paad_ebspma`.`turmas` 
ON (`sala_ocupacao`.`id_turma` = `turmas`.`id_turma`)
where`ebspma_paad_ebspma`.`sala_ocupacao`.`id_turma` = '$turma' 
GROUP BY  `ebspma_paad_ebspma`.`sala_ocupacao`.`id_dia` ,  `ebspma_paad_ebspma`.`req_material_tempo`.`inicio` ASC";
```

Running this query i have almost records but this is a school timetable and when a class is divided in 2 groups i have two classrooms for this class. With this query i have only one group
For exemple the class start at 1 PM in two classrooms (27 and 31), with this query i should have at 1 PM the classroom X is on 27 and 31 classroom, but i have only the first one
Image to check http://postimg.org/image/u24r35fkz/
And my database image http://postimg.org/image/hyvpb1qz1/ce7a7320/

So what's wrong with my query?

Thanks

UPDATE 1

I have simplified my query to

```
SELECT t2.`dia` , t3.`sala` , t4.`inicio` , t1.`id_ocup` , t5.`turma` 
FROM  `ebspma_paad_ebspma`.`sala_ocupacao` AS t1
INNER JOIN  `ebspma_paad_ebspma`.`semana_dias` AS t2 ON ( t1.`id_dia` = t2.`id_dia` ) 
INNER JOIN  `ebspma_paad_ebspma`.`req_material_sala` AS t3 ON ( t1.`id_sala` = t3.`idsala` ) 
LEFT JOIN  `ebspma_paad_ebspma`.`req_material_tempo` AS t4 ON ( t1.`id_tempo` = t4.`idtempo` ) 
LEFT JOIN  `ebspma_paad_ebspma`.`turmas` AS t5 ON ( t1.`id_turma` = t5.`id_turma` ) 
WHERE t1.`id_turma` =12
GROUP BY t1.`id_dia` , t3.`idsala` , t4.`inicio`
```

Now i can see all the classes but not in the right order, the order should be given by t4.`inicio` and by day (id dia)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not grouping by `sala` so MySQL will behave badly and give you a random row that fits the other requirements. Better functioning database engines would give you an error saying you haven't aggregated or grouped all result columns.

If you add `sala` to `GROUP BY` you should see the difference.

For the ordering: you're not asking the database to `ORDER BY` anything so the rows will be in whatever order they happen to come out. Probably want to add `ORDER BY t4.inicio, t1.id_dia` to handle that.

Comment: @gmc1972 Added info about that. You need to actually ask for the DB to sort it the way you want.

Comment: Yes, you are right  did that and now i have all records. Thanks to all